# What is the proper usage of the menu.addIntentOptions()?

Tags: android

I don't understand the correct usage of `menu.addIntentOptions()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best example would be the contact manager. If you install ZXing Teams Barcode Scanner, open a contact in your contact manager and open the menu then you will get an option to generate a QR code for that contact.

This could of course also be another software doing just that for you as it simply represents a hook for software able to do that. You can define such options yourself with that method and of course you can define an application which would perform a certain action yourself.

Comment: The scanner doesnt have that option anymore i think.